# Android onTouchListener with ImageView and PDFRenderer

Tags: android, listener, pdfrenderer

Can some body help me with some understanding about `onTouchListners`??
I am new to android...and doing something more complex I guess..

**1. I have a main Activity class which renders a list of 7 pdf files**

**2. there exists a PDF class which renders the selected item as a new pdf file(done using pdf renderer)**

**3. there exists a flip class to take care of flipping pages on touch**

I am confused about, where to place the following method as it is never getting called if placed correctly and it shud help me deliver the next or previous pdf page..

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         return gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
   }
```

Thank u..

Comment: show some code..what u have tried till now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple explanation of how OnTouch works...

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
    int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(event);
    int x = (int)MotionEventCompat.getX(event,pointerIndex);
    int y = (int)MotionEventCompat.getY(event,pointerIndex);

    switch(action)
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //
        // First finger was touched. Set "pointerIndex" to some value (lets say 0 or -1)
        // Save "pointerIndex" corresponding to this touched object.
        //
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        //
        // More finger touched when first finger is already touched.
        // Save "pointerIndex" corresponding to this touched object.
        //
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        //
        // Finger with "pointerIndex" was moved.
        //
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //
        // The first touched finger went off.
        //
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        //
        // Finger with "pointerIndex" went off (other than first finger)
        //
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Good Luck. :)

Comment: Thank you for the above reference..but the issue is when i zoom imageview, the page gets zoomed along with that the page is either moved to the next page..the page is not held..

Comment: I have implemented the flips using xml and the zoom using gestureListener both seem to be overriding...any suggestions plzz??

Comment: In my PDF Renderer I have implemented the flips using xml and the zoom using gesture Listener, It has has following concern -

When I zoom the page, it does not slide up, down, right or left correctly
When I zoom the page and tap with two fingers close the page gets zoomed out and tap with two fingers far apart the page gets zoomed in leaving its actual co-ordinates..